# Flask Application Using Mod_WSGI on Windows won't run - Now URLS won't work

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

EDIT: I'm slightly further along now, but the new issue is around rendering templates.  When I go to any URL I get the following error message in the log:

server:666/ gives this error

```
[error] [client 192.168.100.109] client denied by server configuration: C:/I4/importicusindex.html
```

and server:666/export gives this error

```
error] [client 192.168.100.109] client denied by server configuration: C:/I4/importicusexport
```

It must be reading the .py file as it knows to look for index.html when accessing "/" or is that just default behaviour?

---

I'm struggling to get my application running in APACHE on Windows using MOD_WSGI.  I've browsed a few answers on here already and tried following the documentation but to no avail.

The app itself runs fine using flask's inbuilt server.

**c:\i4\importicus\wsgi\importicus.WSGI**

```
import sys
sys.path.append('c:/i4/importicus/')
activate_this = 'c:/i4/importicus/importicus.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
import importicus as importicus
```

**vhosts file**

```
<VirtualHost *:666>
    ServerAdmin imats@copyright.com.au
    DocumentRoot "c:/i4/importicus"

    ErrorLog c:/i4/importicus/logs/engine-error_log
    CustomLog c:/i4/importicus/logs/engine-access_log common



    Alias /media c:/i4/importicus/static
    <Directory c:/i4/importicus>

        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>



    WSGIScriptAlias /wsgi z:\i4\importicus\wsgi\importicus.wsgi

    <Directory c:/i4/importicus/wsgi>

        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**c:\i4\importicus\importicus.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template,jsonify, request
from werkzeug import secure_filename
import importicus_functions
import ast, os, sys
importicus_main = Flask(__name__)

UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'uploads'
importicus_main.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

#print importicus_main.config.keys()#['ROOT_PATH']='C:/IMATS-Project/legacy import scripts/importicus/'
importicus_main.debug=True


@importicus_main.route('/')
def importicus():

    return render_template('splash.html')
```

The only error I get is:

**Forbidden**

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

so apache is obviously finding the WSGI file, but my suspicion is that I'm not running the flask application correctly.

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Did you check the permissions on the .wsgi file?

Comment: Yep, full permissions for all users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WSGIScriptAlias /wsgi z:\i4\importicus\wsgi\importicus.wsgi` is the problem, you will note that all other paths are on **c:**, not **z:**

Infuriating!